# How do you make a bot send a message to an specific guild in a specific channel without using commands

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Anyone there can help me? I'm just trying to make the bot send a message to a specified channel without requesting it, the message should be send every x minutes but I just want know how to send it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) (the list of all the guilds the client is a member of) and [Guild.channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) (the list of all the channels the guild has).
To specify the guild and the channel you can use their IDs: if you enable developer mode in Discord (under User settings > Appearance > Advanced) you can right-click to copy the ID of guilds, channels, users and so on.
Once you have the ID, you can use `Collection.get()` to get them. Alternatively you can `.find()` them by name, but that's not ideal because names can be changed.

Here's an example:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.get('your guild ID as a string here'), // returns a Guild or undefined
  channel; 

if (guild) {
  channel = guild.channels.get('your channel ID as a string here');
  if (channel) setInterval(() => {channel.send("Here you can put the message and stuffs.");}, 10 * 60 * 1000);
  else console.log("There's no channel with that ID."),
} else console.log("There's no guild with that ID.");
```

This is only the core concept, you can obviously modify that.

Answer (score 0):

let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('your guild ID as a string here'), // returns a Guild or undefined
channel;

if (guild) {
channel = guild.channels.cache.get('your channel ID as a string here');
if (channel) setInterval(() => {channel.send("Here you can put the message and stuffs.");}, 10 * 60 * 1000);
else console.log("There's no channel with that ID."),
} else console.log("There's no guild with that ID.");

Comment: Hey, you can use markdown format of the text if you code contains some code, please check out the link, [markdown getting started](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started) & [markdown cheat sheet](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).